# Next.js - Is there a way to globally set a default image that loads if the main image does not load

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

So currently I am using this bit of code inside my components to load a placeholder image if the main one does not load.

```
<img
  src={image ? image : 'images/placeholder-image.png'}
/>
```

And this works fine, however I have to set this for each img tag I use.
So I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to globally (for every img tag in a project) set a default image that would load in case there was an error loading the main image?

Comment: Create a custom image component and use it instead of regular old `img`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to have a fallback image in NextJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66953317) -- set a default value of `fallbackSrc` in that answer so that you don't have to explicitly write it each time.

Comment: Yes these are both great answers, thank you! I will update the question with the answer soon.