# NextJS stuck when image is not found

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

My NextJS 12 App is stuck loading when the image provided doesn't exist, there is a way to solve that?

```js
import Image from "next/image";

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        src="/image_dont_exist"
        alt="Image don't exist"
        width={400}
        height={400}
        objectFit="cover"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The page just keep loading forever

Comment: Refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949606/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-fallback-image-in-nextjs - It extends the image to go to a fallback

Comment: Your code is working, for my test: your code tries to load image, then showing alt text. What do you expect?