# Set a default value for Image src in next.js

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js

i'm trying to set a default value for image src in the `Image` component in next.js.
i can't find any option to do that, for case the server response with status code 400.
corrently i'm getting in the console text like:

```
The requested resource isn't a valid image for <url for invalid image here> received inode/x-empty
```

i want to return a default image in case the requested image doesn't found.
thanks in advece!

i tried to build a component like:

```
const CustomImage = ({
                         src = placeholder,
                         alt = "alt",
                         size = "125px",
                         cycle = false
                     }) => {
    return <Image
        src={src}
        width={size}
        height={size}
        alt={alt}
        quality={"100"}
        layout={"fixed"}
        style={{
            borderRadius:
                cycle ? "50%" : ".15em"
        }}
    />
}
```

and it doesn't help.

EDIT:
after a lot of searching, i have a component that should take care of all the cases, but when i'm getting 404 error it stil showing broken image.

```js
const CustomImage = ({
                         src = placeholder,
                         alt = "alt",
                     }) => {

    const [imageError, setImageError] = useState(false);

    return <Image
        src={imageError ? placeolder : src}
        width={size}
        height={size}
        alt={alt}
        onLoadingComplete={(result) => {
            if (result.naturalWidth === 0) setImageError(true)
        }}
        onError={(event) => setImageError(true)}
        onEmptied={() => setImageError(true)}
    />
}
```

Comment: Add the default image into the public folder and try like this ```<Image src={originalImageUrl ?? /Default image} />```

Comment: Doesn't help :)

Comment: This looks similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949606/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-fallback-image-in-nextjs - do any of those solutions help?

Comment: @JohnDetlefs for some cases it doesn't work

Comment: Which cases does it not work for?

Comment: @JohnDetlefs empty response

Comment: @YeudaBy - you haven't answered julio's question... for which cases does it not work for?

Comment: When i'm getting 404 error from the server. on the console the error showing up, but ```onError``` doesn't handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, the right way to do that is by `onErrorCapture`.