# Next/image with unknown hostname

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to figure out how to deal with unknown hostname in next/image. I try this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949606/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-fallback-image-in-nextjs), but it didn't work. Is there anyway to solve this issue.

Expected: set imgSrc when unknown hostname occur

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.