# How to handle Nextjs image error with app directory?

Tags: next.js

I am using app directory on Nextjs and wondering if it's possible to render the image on the server and handle its error with a fallback image there?

If it's not possible, I guess this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949606/what-is-the-best-way-to-have-a-fallback-image-in-nextjs) can be folowed.

```
import React from "react"
import Image, { ImageProps } from "next/image"

interface Props extends ImageProps {
  p?: HTMLImageElement
  blurDataURL?: string
  fill?: boolean
}

function ImageWithFallback(props: Props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Image
        placeholder="blur"
        blurDataURL="/icons/placeholder.png"
        {...props}
        onError={(e) => {
            e.currentTarget.src = "/icons/placeholder.png"
         }}
        draggable="false"
        loading="lazy"
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default ImageWithFallback
```